# Don't show duplicates posts, when tags of this post are equal to one topic

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've got topics with corresponding tags, when user add corresponding tag to post, this post will display on this topic: 
[image]

as you can see, if my corresponding tags, like "js" and "css" on image, equal to **one** post, my post duplicates, how I can remove this duplicate and show only one post, that have "css" and "js" tags.

**"get corresponding tags by topic" model:**

```
function getTopicTagsByTopicId($i)
{
    $this->db->where('topic_tags.id_topic', $i);
    $this->db->join('user_topics', 'topic_tags.id_topic = user_topics.topic_id', 'left');
    $query = $this->db->get('topic_tags');
    return $query->result_array(); 
}
```

**"get posts by corresponding tag of the topic" model:**

```
function getTopicPostsByCorrespondingTagSlug($i, $u)
{
    $this->db->join('posts_tags', "posts_tags.postid = posts.post_id AND posts_tags.creator_id =$u", 'left');
    $this->db->join('tags', "tags.id_tag = posts_tags.tagid", 'left');
    $this->db->where('tags.tag_slug', $i);
    $query = $this->db->get("posts");       
    return $query->result_array();  
}
```

**view:**

```
    <?php foreach($topics as $topic): ?>

            <div class="spacer"></div>
            <div class="topic small" data-topic-id="<?php echo $topic['topic_id']; ?>">

                <a class="showProgress"><?php echo $topic['topic_name']; ?></a>

                <?php if ( $topic['user_id'] == $this->session->userdata('userid') ) { ?> 
                    <a class="edit" title="Edit Topic">
                        <div class="icon">
                            <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <a class="remove-topic" rel="nofollow" title="Remove <?php echo $topic['topic_name']; ?> topic">
                      <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                    </a>
                <?php } ?>

            </div>

                <?php $topic_tags = $this->stories_model->getTopicTagsByTopicId($topic['topic_id']); ?>
                <?php if (count($topic_tags)>0): ?>
                    <div class="spacer-small"></div>
                    <?php foreach($topic_tags as $topic_tag): ?>
                        <p><?php echo $topic_tag['slug_tag']; ?></p>
                        <?php $corresponding_tags = $this->stories_model->getTopicPostsByCorrespondingTagSlug($topic_tag['slug_tag'], $u['user_id']); ?>
                        <?php if ( count( $corresponding_tags ) > 0 ) : ?>
                            <div class="feed-items" data-links-tag="<?php echo $topic_tag['slug_tag']; ?>">
                                <?php foreach( $corresponding_tags as $corresponding_tag ) : ?>

                                    <div class="link" data-link-id="<?php echo $corresponding_tag['post_id']; ?>" id="link-<?php echo $corresponding_tag['post_id']; ?>">
                                        <a href="<?php echo $corresponding_tag['post_url']; ?>"><?php echo $corresponding_tag['post_subject']; ?></a>
                                    </div>

                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif; ?>

                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
```

**my DB:**

user_topics:

[image]

topic_tags:

[image]

Comment: Surely if you show items that have tag1 AND tag2 you'd need a new tag within the topic? Why not just create a "Tag 1 and Tag2" tag and assign items to that?

Comment: I want to show posts with equal tags in one topic that has this two tags as corresponding

Comment: So, in your example, you don't want it to display under the PS tag, but still want it shown under the CSS and JS tags?

Comment: @JamieBicknell no, if post has two or more tags, that equals to "topic corresponding tags" i don't want to dublicate this post, i want to show one post that has this two equal tags. see "js" and "css" where a one post that dublicates..

Comment: That's what I was getting at in my first comment. In this case, in what tag should the item be displayed; CSS or JS? Is it based alphabetically, or based on the order of tag importance on the item?

Comment: @JamieBicknell i think don't matter, the main mission - hide dublicate post :)

Comment: In that case for each topic just create an temp array, and store the ID of the item in the array and for each item check whether the item ID exists in the array, if it does then it's already been outputted so don't display.

Comment: @JamieBicknell can you please provide some code example as unswer, i'm tired with this code and endless foreach in my "view" :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115292/discussion-between-stefan-and-jamie-bicknell).

Comment: You should get this list in a single database query. All the tables in your above queries are related to each other. You pretty much perform a join in php code which is not too efficient solution.

Comment: @Shadow hmm, can you please provide, if you have some time, more efficient solution? thanks (

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the 2 methods in a single method with a single database query, since the tables in the currently used 2 methods are related. I know sql better, so I'm providing you an sql based solution, you can adapt it to codeigniter.

```
select topic_tags.slug_tag, t1.post_id, t1.post_url, t1.post_subject
from topic_tags 
inner join user_topics on topic_tags.id_topic = user_topics.topic_id
left join
    (select max(topic_tags.slug_tag) as unique_slug_tag, posts.post_id, posts.post_url, posts.post_subject
    from topic_tags 
    inner join user_topics on topic_tags.id_topic = user_topics.topic_id
    inner join tags on tags.tag_slug = topic_tags.slug_tag
    inner join posts_tags on tags.id_tag = posts_tags.tagid
    inner join posts on posts_tags.postid = posts.post_id AND posts_tags.creator_id =$u
    where topic_tags.id_topic = $i
    group by posts.post_id, posts.post_url, posts.post_subject) t1 on topic_tags.slug_tag = t1.unique_slug_tag
where topic_tags.id_topic = $i
```

The subquery gets you the list of posts by associated tags, a post appears under a single tag only thanks to the group by. The tag will be the highest tag name per alphabetical order (max()). The outer query gets all the tags the topic is associated with and gets the associated posts (if any) for each of them.

$i and $u are parameters that need to be supplied by your php program similarly to how they are used in the current code.

Comment: ok, huge thanks, i will try this now and unswer you in couple of minutes :)

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select max(topic_tags.slug_tag) as unique_slug_tag, posts.post_id, posts.post_ur' at line 3` :(

Comment: Missed the opening bracket for the subquery.

Comment: got sql error `Not unique table/alias: 'posts_tags'`

Comment: added to the my function `getTopicPostsByCorrespondingTagSlug` and call with parameters `getTopicPostsByCorrespondingTagSlug( $topic['topic_id'], $u['user_id'] ); `

Comment: This not what I have asked. Syntax errors are relatively easy to identify and correct. Apart from posting the errors, have done anything to try to understand how the query should work and what may have caused the error message? I missed an `on` keyword from one of the join conditions.

Comment: works! man, don't know how to say thanks to you, you are awesome!

Comment: Glad to be able to help :)